# Sending data from html to python flask server "GET / HTTP/1.1" 405 error

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

very new to python/AJAX and have been piecing everything from examples on the internet/flask documentation and I've gotten so far. Basically what I am trying to do is send latitude and longitude coordinates on a click (from mapbox API) to flask, and have that data print to console (to prove it has successfully gone Flask so I can work with it later).

data I am trying to send is formatted as:

```
LngLat {lng: 151.0164794921875, lat: -33.79572045486767}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick=submit() type="button">POST</button>

<script>    
map.on('click', function (e) { 
console.log(e.lngLat)
});

function submit() {
var myData = e.lngLat
$.post( "/", $( "myData" ).serialize() 
);
}
</script>
```

PY:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def home():
return render_template('index.html')
print(request.form['myData'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

when I try to run from console to localhost:5000 I get the error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Sept/2016 23:21:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

I'm sorry if this is a silly question but I'm stumped for now! Thank you for your input

Comment: There is no code that handle any time of POST data.

Comment: what does your chrome debugger network traffic look like?

Comment: you also need to fix your indents and move your print statement above the return statement in your route

Answer (score 2):

In your route, allow `GET` method, otherwise the html wil never render.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```

To print lat/lng to the console, first check if the method is `POST`, then print it:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.form.get('lng'), request.form.get('lat'))
```

This is the resulting code for the route:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form.get('lng'), request.form.get('lat'))
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting 405 error is because you only have `home()` controller, that accept only `POST` methods. And you are trying to get response with `GET` method.

So you need to change `methods` argument in `@app.route()` decorator

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

But still, you don't have any code that would handle your AJAX request.